# How to solve the equation${d^2x}\over {dt^2}$-t${{d^3x}\over {dt^3}}$+$({{d^3x}\over {dt^3}})^3$=0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

How to solve the equation 
$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} -t \frac{d^3 x} {dt^3} + \left(\frac{d^3x}{dt^3}\right)^3 = 0.$$

I supposed $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = p$ , and then I can know that $p-t \frac{dp}{dt}+\left(\frac{dp}{dt}\right)^2=0$, however, I don't know how to continue. Can somebody tell me how to solve the differential equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a good approach.

We have:

$$x'' = p \implies x''' = p'$$

Rewriting, we have:

- $p + (p')^3 - t p' = 0$
- $p =  t p'-(p')^3$
- $p' = t p'' + p' - 3(p')^2 p''$
- $p' = p' + p''(t-3(p')^2)$
- $p''(t - 3(p')^2) = 0$

This gives us two items to solve:

$$p'' = 0, t - 3(p')^2 = 0$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh, I can solve it now. Thanks

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you for sharing. How did you figure this out?